# Android : Cannot return the values

Tags: java, android, android-studio, return-value, return-type

I have created a simple Layout to get information from users, and i have java programmed it to get the data and store them in an .JSON format. I took it as a string and saved them into .JSON format. But while returning `return jsonObject` i get an error.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText firstname, lastname, username, mail_id, mobile_no, pass;
Button submit;

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String FILE_NAME = "Sample.json";


    firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastname);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    mail_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mail);
    mobile_no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);





    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            jsonformat();

            String userString = jsonObject.toString();

            File file = new File(MainActivity.this.getFilesDir(), FILE_NAME);
            FileWriter fileWriter;
            try {
                fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                bufferedWriter.write(userString);
                bufferedWriter.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            File file1 = new File(MainActivity.this.getFilesDir(), FILE_NAME);
            FileReader fileReader = null;
            try {
                fileReader = new FileReader(file1);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // This responce will have Json Format String
            String responce = stringBuilder.toString();

        }
    });


}
public JSONObject jsonformat()
{
    try {
        jsonObject.put("fname", firstname); // seems that it's wrong.
        jsonObject.put("lname", lastname); // seems that it's wrong.
        jsonObject.put("uname", username); // seems that it's wrong.
        jsonObject.put("mail", mail_id); // seems that it's wrong.
        jsonObject.put("Phone Number", mobile_no); // seems that it's wrong.
        jsonObject.put("Password", pass); // seems that it's wrong.

        //return jsonObject; // The error -- You can't return jsonObject in here. onCreate method is void method.
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}
```

}

Build error:

```
/home/sim/AndroidStudioProjects/Activity/app/src/main/java/com/example/activity                  /MainActivity.java:55: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
        return jsonObject;
               ^

   The .JSON file is created as per the program in the directory. But doesn't contain any value in it. just some "id" has been printed.

   Dunno where  did i make mistake or missed logic. Comment my mistakes.
```

Comment: `protected void onCreate(` - of course you can return something

Comment: You even have code that uses the object afterwards `String userString = jsonObject.toString();` - what are you trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to get the input and store them in .JSON file in .JSON format

Comment: If i use JUST "RETURN" it returns some type of ID, But i need  "RETURN jsonOject". It shows this error " error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
        return jsonObject;"

Comment: You are in your `onCreate` method which does not return anything.

Comment: you have written the code in onCreate, when you fetch values from EditTexts at creation, it will be empty, so basically you are writing empty values.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code contains some wrong logic.
first, you cannot return onCreate method. you should make seperate method to return object. I think that your code don't need return.

Second, you did put "Layout Element instance" to JSONObject.
I cannot understand why you did it.

Anyway, I changed your MainActivity code as following.
So you can made your change in new MainActivity code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText firstname, lastname, username, mail_id, mobile_no, pass;
    Button submit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String FILE_NAME = "Sample.json";


        firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstname);
        lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastname);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        mail_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mail);
        mobile_no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);

        submit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonformat();
            String userString = jsonObject.toString();

            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), FILE_NAME);
            FileWriter fileWriter;
            try {
                fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                bufferedWriter.write(userString);
                bufferedWriter.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            File file1 = new File(this.getFilesDir(), FILE_NAME);
            FileReader fileReader = null;
            try {
                fileReader = new FileReader(file1);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // This responce will have Json Format String
            String responce = stringBuilder.toString();

        });
    }

    public JSONObject jsonformat() {
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
       try {
           jsonObject.put("fname", firstname.getText().toString());
           jsonObject.put("lname", lastname.getText().toString());
           jsonObject.put("uname", username.getText().toString());
           jsonObject.put("mail", mail_id.getText().toString());
           jsonObject.put("Phone Number", mobile_no.getText().toString());
           jsonObject.put("Password", pass.getText().toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have even created a separate method, but it didn,t return any value

Comment: Can you update your post with your current? And It's correct put element instance?

Comment: Sorry @ Daniel.Wang. I have no idea about element instance Since an new to android.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check it.